# One 'case' not working in a simple 'switch' statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm doing some basic stuff from the book "Principles and Practices C++" and I can't work out why the following code doesn't work for the 'euro' output.

If I enter `50e`, for example, it gives me the `default` case and says `"Sorry, I don't recognise ' ' as a currency."` However, if I type `50 e` with a space, it works.  None of the other cases require a space.

I can't work out the issue.  I know it's basic, but I'm still learning.

Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    const double yen_to_dollar = 0.0094;
    const double euro_to_dollar = 1.24;
    const double pound_to_dollar = 1.40;
    double amount = 0.0;
    char currency = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter how much money you have followed by 'e' 'y' or 'p' (for euro, yen or pounds):\n";
    cin>>amount>>currency;
    switch (currency){
        case 'y':
            cout << amount << " Yen == " << yen_to_dollar*amount << " Dollars\n";
            break;
        case 'p':
            cout << amount << " Pounds == " << pound_to_dollar*amount << " 
            Dollars\n";
            break;
        case 'e':
            cout << amount << " Euros == " << euro_to_dollar*amount <<" Dollars\n";
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Sorry, I don't recognise '" << currency << "' as a currency.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 50e is a number in scientific notation, so that how its being treated

Comment: @Mitchel0022 so I can't use 'e' as an input variable?

Comment: You'd have to parse it with another function, such as a regex.

Comment: If you take your input as wide characters (which admittedly requires some special tricks for Windows), you could use the actual € and ¥ symbols.

Comment: @Davislor: Don't use wide characters. You just move the goalposts with your encoding trouble. If you want to use non-ASCII, use an actual UTF-8 library.

Comment: Don't store currency as floating point values. Use fixed-point, i.e. an integer. "Number of pennies" is probably okay in your case; sometimes a lower division is needed.

Comment: One workaround if you want to use `sscanf()` is, instead of a `case` block, attempt to parse the formats `123.45e`, `123e`, `123.45p`, `123p` and `123Y`, taking the first that matches.  You can do this with `[]` format specifiers.. This should also work with UTF-8 if your locale is set correctly.

Comment: Also, Windows is the odd OS out when it comes to supporting UTF-8. You can do it, but it’ll be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that e.g. `50e` is parsed as a floating point number you can read in the line as a string using `getline`, and find the letter position. Then parse the numerical part (before the letter position) using e.g. `std::stod`.

---

For the idea of using an UTF-8 console i/o library (the only reasonable one that comes to mind is my own [*stdlib*](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/stdlib)) and actual “€” and “¥”, be aware that these characters are represented with more than one `char` value as UTF-8 (a bit incompatible with direct use of `switch`, though you could `map` them to numerical currency id's), and that they can be difficult to type.

That is, UTF-8 console i/o has its own problems for this particular case.